# How to get multiple dl/dt/dd tags on the same line

Tags: html, css

I need to get multiple information on the same line this:

**Name**: Robert   **Age**: 10   **Gender**: Male

Where the labels are different colors from the value. How would I do this?

Comment: Where's your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `dt` and `dd` tags have `display: block` set from the browser. Just reset that to `display: inline` or `inline-block` to make them on the same line.

```css
dt, dd {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
}
dt {
  font-weight: bold;
}
dt:after {
  content: ":";
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt>Name</dt>
  <dd>Robert</dd>
  <dt>Age</dt>
  <dd>10</dd>
  <dt>Gender</dt>
  <dd>Male</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: While it isn't really important, the colon in the question isn't bold while it is in the answer, which could be solved by adding `font-weight: normal;` to dt:after